# Replacement of primary sampling unit (PSU) due to natural disaster

Tags: sampling, survey

In a health survey, we are using two stage cluster sampling.

In first stage, we have a list of 500 villages in district and we will select 16 villages (PSU) using systematic random sampling.

In second stage we will select, 12 households at random from each selected PSUs. District wise sample size is 192 household.

But in practical situation, we get 4 PSUs are highly affected by flood. It is not possible to collect data from these PSUs or villages.

In these circumstances, how can we replace this PSUs? What is the best sampling procedure? Could anybody give any suggestions regarding this?

Comment: Please clarify: You appear to say that there are four inaccessible villages in the list of 500.  Is that correct?

Comment: Bascially, 4 PSUs are affected by flood among my selected 16 PSUs at the time of survey. In totat, 500 PSUs there may be more PSUs which are affected. Due to environmental situation, it is not possible to ensure specifically about the accessibility of the 500 PSUs.

Answer (score 3):

From a methodological point of view the best option would be to limit your sampling frame of villages prior to sampling. By going through the villages and determining the accessibility of each village you will be left with an accurate sampling frame of an accessible population. Of course your sample will only be representative of the accessible populations of the district, but this way you won't have to deal with potential criticizes of your study based on replacement procedures.

Comment: I agree with this approach. This is acknowledged, for example on page 58 of this UN Document: http://unstats.un.org/unsd/hhsurveys/pdf/Household_surveys.pdf

I think however that whatever survey is done should sample systematically with probability proportional to village size.  If this is not done  and if villages differ in size, with a predominance of smaller villages, then simply taking a 1 in K systematic sample will over-represent the portion of the population that lives in smaller villages.

Comment: 1. It remains for @Rudroi88 to clarify if there are more than four unavailable villages in the population.  
2. An alternative to replacement is to re-weight the remaining samples.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There may be more than 4 inaccessible villages.

Comment: 25% of  the sample is inaccessible, so a point estimate of the number affected is 125 with standard error  47.  But I suspect you can do better based on your local knowledge of the disaster and geography.

So, @david rae's suggestion is still the best, but you will be unable to say what part of the population is represented by the existing sample until you do more to assess the number and percent of villages that cannot be surveyed. This would be easier if there is a "diasaster zone", which you exclude , regardless of the possibility that some villages in the zone might be available.

Comment: @AnthonyDamico, I agree.  In this situation, I don't think that replacements are not appropriate.  It would be okay to to take additional villages in the "available" part of the population, the effective "sampled population". To avoid unequal weights, the best approach would be to resample that "stratum" from scratch, if possible.